# Spring webflux bean validation not working

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, bean-validation, spring-webflux

I am trying to use bean validation in Webflux. This is what I have so far:

```
@PostMapping("contact")
fun create(@RequestBody @Valid contact: Mono<Contact>) : Mono<Contact> {
    return contact.flatMap { contactRepository.save(it) }
            .doOnError{ Error("test") }
}
```

The The validation doesn't work... I would expect that the `Error("test")` would be shown...

Does someone has a working example(Java or Kotlin)?

**UPDATE**

Here is a repository so it can be reproducted: https://github.com/jwz104/webflux-validation-test

Request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/tickets \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "email": "",
    "name": "",
    "message": ""
}'
```

Renamed contact to ticket, but everything is still the same.

Comment: have you tried binding an `Errors` or `BindingResult` argument in your handler method signature?

Comment: @BrianClozel I tried both, but I get the same result... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10950 has the same issue with a fix. But that fix is the `onErrorXX` and doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information so we can reproduce it? The Contact class and the actual request sent (a curl command) would be nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The annotations you have placed in the example project are actually annotations on the constructor parameters of the `Ticket` class. For Spring validation, you need to annotate the fields instead. You can do this in Kotlin by using [annotation use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets).

In this specific case, your Ticket class should look like this:

```
data class Ticket(
        @field:Id
        @field:JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
        val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),

        @field:Email
        @field:Max(200)
        @field:NotEmpty
        val email: String,

        @field:NotEmpty
        @field:Size(min = 2, max = 200)
        val name: String,

        @field:NotEmpty
        @field:Size(min = 10, max = 2000)
        val message: String
)
```

This, along with the following controller function will work and return errors as expected:

```
@PostMapping("tickets")
fun create(@RequestBody @Valid contact: Mono<Ticket>) : Mono<Ticket> {
    return contact.flatMap { ticketRepository.save(it) }
            .doOnError{ Error("test") }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to combine few of the answers from SO to get the validation correct.
What I did was:

- Made my data class as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48508749/8389034).

  - Then i used `javax.validation.Validator` class to validate the data
    class.

`import javax.validation.Validator
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`

```
@Service
open class MyService {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: UserRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var validator: Validator

     open fun createUser(user: User): Mono<User> {
         val violations = validator.validate(user)
          //if it violates our constraints, it will throw an exception, which we 
          //handle using global exception handler
          if(violations.isNotEmpty()){
               throw ConstraintViolationException(violations)
           }
           return repo.save(user)
         }
. . .
}
```

- Add these lines in application.properties.

> ```
> spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
> spring.resources.add-mappings=false
> ```

And to catch the exceptions.

```
@RestControllerAdvice    
open class ExceptionHandlers {

  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException::class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  fun throwConstraintViolationExcetion(ex: ConstraintViolationException): ApiResponse {
    return ApiResponse (message= ex.message.toString(), data= null);
  }
}
```

p.s `ApiResponse` is just a data class that takes server message & data as parameters.
No need to handle errors in `@Controller` as it will be thrown by the `@Service` class

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `bindingResult: BindingResult` to as an extra parameter.  When the method begins you can do something like `bindingResult.isValid()`.  We use an aspect over all controller methods to return an error message with the validation errors to the user.

Comment: I get `Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult' `

Comment: There is no method `isValid()`.

Comment: The correct method in [`BindingResult`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) is [`hasErrors()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#hasErrors--).