# How to catch exceptions from spring webflux controller?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am using javax validations in my controller with `@Valid @RequestBody`. When the server receives invalid data it throws error but I want to handle that error and return custom formatted error. I am unable to catch exception in my controller advice. I am using spring webFlux so can't use the bindingResult. How can I handle that exception? Here is my code

Controller

```
    @PostMapping
    fun createPerson(@Valid @RequestBody resource: PersonResource): Mono<Person> {
        return personService.save(resource.toPerson())
    }
```

Resource

```
data class PersonResource(
    val id: String?,

    @field:NotEmpty
    val name: String,
    ...
}
```

ErrorHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ApiErrorHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException::class)
    fun handleValidationErrors(e: IllegalArgumentException): ResponseEntity<*> {
    // never reaches here
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48508749/9164471 solution will work for you. Declare the parameter as Mono<PersonResource> and handle the error with doOnError()

Answer (score 2):

I think you are catching a different exception. I am using `@ControllerAdvice` to catch [`WebExchangeBindException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebExchangeBindException.html) as validation errors and it worked for me.

> A specialization of ServerWebInputException thrown when after data binding and validation failure. Implements BindingResult (and its super-interface Errors) to allow for direct analysis of binding and validation errors.